# Convert Flux<DataBuffer> into Flux<ByteBuffer>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am working on spring webflux file upload. From the controller I want to upload the file on amazon S3 bucket. So in the controller I received following object

```
org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.FilePart
```

And from the `FilePart.content()` I can get

```
reactor.core.publisher.Flux<org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer>
```

My question is how can I convert this `Flux<DataBuffer>` into `Flux<ByteBuffer>`. I mean into the following object

```
Flux<java.nio.ByteBuffer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer#asByteBuffer()`:

```
Flux<java.nio.ByteBuffer> buffers = filePart.content()
    .map(DataBuffer::asByteBuffer);
```

Comment: this method is deprecated. new approach is to use something like readableByteBuffers

Answer (score 3):

The [`asByteBuffer()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBuffer.html#asByteBuffer()) method mentioned in the [answer of tmarwen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69570324/1915448) is deprecated **since Spring Boot 3.x** (and Spring framework 6.x). The following deprecation warning is added:

> **Deprecated.**
> *as of 6.0, in favor of `toByteBuffer(ByteBuffer)`, `readableByteBuffers()`, or `writableByteBuffers()`.*

If you're using the `DataBuffer` to upload a file, `readableByteBuffers()` can be used. This method returns an `Iterator<ByteBuffer>` so you can use it with `Flux.fromIterable()`:

```java
Flux<ByteBuffer> byteBuffers = filePart
    .content()
    // The `flatMapSequential` is important for larger buffers to preserve order
    . flatMapSequential(dataBuffer -> Flux.fromIterable(dataBuffer::readableByteBuffers));
```

**IMPORTANT**: The `readableByteBuffers()` method was added in Spring Boot 3.0.3 (Spring framework 6.0.5) while the deprecation warning is present since Spring Boot 3.0.0 (Spring framework 6.0.0). This means you have to upgrade your project to at least Spring Boot 3.0.3 to make this work.

Comment: In my experience, using readableByteBuffers() instead of asByteBuffer() leads to corruption. Couldn't figure out why. My guess is either the iterator is not read in order or it's not closed properly.

Comment: Using `flatMapSequential` instead of `flatMap` solved the issue I had.

Comment: the doc warns that the returned iterator must be used in a try-with-resources clause or explicitly closed. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBuffer.html#readableByteBuffers()